# Neo4J and timestamps

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I need information about node's creation & last modification dates...

Is there a way to automatically handle `created` and `updated` properties for a node?

Hibernate offers `@Version` for `updated` field. Is there something similar with Node4J.

I found http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/classes/Neo4j/Rails/Timestamps.html but it seems to be only available for Ruby.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587800/audits-with-spring-data-neo4j.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use annotations form the spring-data-commons library. Use [@CreatedDate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/CreatedDate.html) and [@LastModifiedDate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/commons/docs/1.5.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/annotation/LastModifiedDate.html) on properties of type Long. Make sure you're using the simple mapping mode. For now, advanced mapping mode does not support this, see [DATAGRAPH-335](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-335).